# Cromium developer tools search all sources gets slower and slower

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I have chromium 55.0.2883.87 on Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1 LTS

When first I start chromium and run a search in the dev tools the results come back dead fast (few milliseconds) but with each search it gets slower and slower ending up with 30 or so seconds

Anyone know what can cause this, it didn't happen with previous versions of chrome.

Comment: Try searching https://crbug.com for an existing bug report ([random example](https://crbug.com/661912)) or submit a new one.

Comment: Thanks, looks like there is a bug open for this (at least it's similar) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=673540&q=devtools%20search%20slow&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified